# Do we need to create sample questions?

Tags: discussion

I see more and more unclear questions with vague description and little information provided. Questions that is impossible to understand, or at the very best, some magic is required to guess what the OP is doing, or trying to do.

Could we create a couple sample questions, to demonstrate how a good question should be made, structured and what info should contain?

Not sure where we could host these sample questions, but when we face a poor question, we could post a link to them, in order for the OP to see it and try to follow the scheme.

In contrast we can also demonstrate what a bad question is, even use some of the existing and closed bad questions - or show the same question as bad and how it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Good idea.

The only place I can think of would be to create sample questions here on meta, or create a new topic on meta with a compiled list of very good questions on JSE.

Comment: I feel that showing how a bad question is and the same question transformed to a good question would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea, but why duplicate content? How about a (Community Wiki) post here on JSE Meta with links to good and bad questions on JSE, there are lots of both. Anyone stumbling over a good or bad question could add it to the list, possibly with a comment on *why* the question is added to the list.

The idea of showing how a bad question can be transformed to a good one is excellent, but again, couldn't we just edit existing questions, and link to the edit history?

Then when someone posts an unclear question, a link to the meta post might help improving the question. There is of course a [How to ask a good question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)-guide, but actual examples are always better.