# Sample Questions - Joomla Support Request Template

Tags: discussion

Following my older question [Do we need to create sample questions?](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227/do-we-need-to-create-sample-questions),

I discovered this **Joomla Support Request Template** from **[Brian Teeman's blog](https://brian.teeman.net/joomla/850-free-joomla-support)**. I think we could use this, or a similar version that may fit in JSE.

Any suggestions, on how to make this visible for new-comers?

## Joomla Support Request Template

- I am having a problem with?'
- Describe the problem (no more than 100 words)
- What version of Joomla are you using (in x.y.z format)?
- Which template are you using?
- Did you try using the default Protostar template?
- When did your problem begin?
- Do you have a backup from before the problem began?
- What resources (exact links) have you read?
- Is this an issue with an extension, if so which one?
- If it is an extension issue have you checked the developers site?
- Link to site so we can see the issue (or screenshots)
- Is registration required to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a tricky one in my opinion. Only problem we face is, we can't change what information the user see's before posting a question, which would be a good guide on how to post a question.

There is a "How to" page, but it's not really visible and most people want a quick a simple solution to their problem, thus they don't bother looking around to see examples of other questions.

I think the best thing we can do is, create a new JSE Meta post, titled (for example) :

"**How to ask a good question?**"

Then we can compile an answer showing the user the relevant information they need to provide us.

When a users asks a new question which is considered too broad, we can simply refer them to this Meta post.

Comment: Still awake? hehe... well having the meta post here for linking on too broad or unclear questions sounds good. We still need to have this post (q/a) created at some point though.

Comment: Only just lol :) Yup, If you create a new topic, I can mock up a community wiki answer in the morning

Comment: I don't see this happening these days from my side... when there is some extra time avail I will give it a try.

Comment: http://meta.joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/250/why-havent-i-received-any-answer-on-my-question/251